# Imported data from excel and assigning variables in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, time-series, jupyter

I have imported data from excel to python and now want to draw multiple plots on a single figure but for that I will need separate variables like 'x' & 'y' etc because we know that `plt.plot(x,y)`, basically I have two datasets in which I am doing Time series analysis. In first data set I have ***Monthly+Yearly*** data in which I combined both columns and formed one column having name **Year-Month**, In second dataset I have ***Daily+Yearly*** data in which I formed one column by merging both and named it as **Year-Daily**. Now the dependent variable in both datasets is the number of **sunspots**.

1. Now I want to Plot Daily and Monthly sunspot numbers on a single Graph in **Python**, so how will I do that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is the library that are you using to import the data?

Comment: please use comments to clarify any information

Comment: I'm using the following for my plots and reading data                                               `import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from openpyxl import load_workbook`